# Access api from a CMS in Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, content-management-system, next.js

Im trying to access an endpoint in next.js from a headless cms proxy in node.js and i cant get it to work. I want to redirect me to a site but instead i get the following error:

> For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector (node:8549)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status
> code 500
> at createError (/home/george/Documents/Coding/NodeJs/node-server/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
> at settle (/home/george/Documents/Coding/NodeJs/node-server/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
> at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/george/Documents/Coding/NodeJs/node-server/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:322:22)
> at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1187:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) (node:8549)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 2) (node:8549) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code. (node:8549) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
> Error: Request failed with status code 500
> at createError (/home/george/Documents/Coding/NodeJs/node-server/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
> at settle (/home/george/Documents/Coding/NodeJs/node-server/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
> at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/george/Documents/Coding/NodeJs/node-server/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:322:22)
> at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1187:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) (node:8549)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 4)

**Proxy localhost:4000**

```
app.get("/test", (req, r, next) => {
  Axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/hello').then((res)=>{

  })
});
```

**Next.js endpoint hello.js localhost:3000**

```
export default (req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.redirect('https://youtube.com');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code inside a `try/catch` block and  probably you will get this error : *res.redirect is not a function*. Which version of next are you using? are you sure that **redirect** response helper is supported in your version? (i think is avaible only in last version - 9.5)

By the way you should still able to use `writeHead` instead:

```
res.writeHead(302, {
  Location: "https://youtube.com",
})
res.end()
```

**Edit**

If you want to redirect in your Proxy you can do something like this:

**Next.js endpoint hello.js localhost:3000**

```
export default (req, res) => {
 res.json({url : "www.youtube.com"})
};
```

**Proxy localhost:4000**

```
app.get("/test", (req,res) => {
  Axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/hello').then((result)=>{
     let {url} = result
     if(url){
        res.redirect(url)
     }
  })
});
```

**Edit2**

I never used preview mode but from what I understood preview mode is just an utility to override satic generation and fetch data from your cms at request time instead that a build time, not a proxy server.
Image that  you create a new post in your headless cms, you want to preview your new blog post but next will fecth that data only at build time, with preview mode you can override this and get a preview of your post so the page will be rendered on request time.
You can see the preview visiting  preview url, or embedd the url in an iframe (i guess).
Note this makes sense only if you pre-render your page with `getStaticProps`.
With `getServerSideProps` you dont need any preview (you will already  fetch the data on every request), but your visitors will  fetch content everytime and is not really necessary, so you can use `getStaticProps`  along with  preview api only for seeing your post draft before publishing.
So i think is a different scenario from your original question.

Comment: You are right, i updated next.js to 9.5 and i dont get this error.But redirection still not happening. Any ideas? How a redirection can happen from a proxy? If i hit the next api from browser, redirection works.

Comment: @GeorgePaouris Of  course redirect works only on Api routes and not in your client or server. Why you should redirect after an api call? what you want to achieve?  if you are trying to make a reverse proxy this is not how you should do.

Comment: I agree with your approach. If you go here https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/preview-mode#securely-accessing-it-from-your-headless-cms, it says something about accessing the preview api from a headless CMS and i figure that it meant a proxy server and thats why i did the above example. So what the docs mean by saying accessing the api from a CMS?

Comment: LIke you said "You can see the preview by visiting preview url", how you can visit the url except from the browser itself? It doesnt give an example with a proxy